# Unable to get a particular solution for a system of ODE equations with the method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I have solved this problem using another method (the method of diagonalisation), but I now want to try with the method of undetermined coefficients and cannot get the right result for $\vec{b}$.

So the system of ODE equations is:

$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}= \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -1 \\
  3 & -2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+ \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}e^t+\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}t$$

I got the solution to the homogeneous equation and now need to get the solution to the non-homogeneous. I am trying with the ansatz  $\vec{x}(t) = \vec{a}te^t + \vec{b}e^t + \vec{c}t + \vec{d}$, for which we have $\vec{x'}(t) = \vec{a}e^t + \vec{a}te^t + \vec{b}e^t + \vec{c}$.

Then I have that: $$\vec{a}=A\vec{a}$$ $$\vec{a}+\vec{b}=A\vec{b}+\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$0=A\vec{c}+\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$\vec{c}=A\vec{d}$$
So I got $\vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$, but for the second one I get $\vec{b}=\vec{0}$, which must be wrong because the final result says that $\vec{b}=-\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  3 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$. The results I get for $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$ are correct though. They are $\vec{c}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{d}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  -1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

The snag comes from the solving of the homogeneous equation : Apparently, you take account of only one basic solution $e^t$ instead of two. The second basic solution is $e^{-t}$ . So, some terms were missing in the pattern of the general solution :

$\vec{x}(t) = \vec{a}te^t + \vec{b}e^t + \vec{c}t + \vec{d}+ \vec{f}te^{-t}+ \vec{g}e^{-t}$

With this,  I got :

$\vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
  3/2 \\
  3/2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}
  c_1 \\
  c_1-(1/2) \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{c}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{d}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  -1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{f}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{g}=\begin{pmatrix}
  c_2 \\
  3c_2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$c_1$ and $c_2$ are the two constants to be determined according to the bounding conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know I needed $e^{-t}$.